# How does Java determine 'file.encoding' system property?

Tags: java, encoding, locale

I thought Java determines 'file.encoding' system property by system locale.

But in my system while system locale is 'ko_kr.UTF-8', 'file.encoding' is 'ANSI_X3.4-1968'.

How does Java determine 'file.encoding' system property?

Comment: This is implementation-dependent. Which JRE? Which operating system?

Comment: Oracle JRE 1.7.0 Update 5 and CentOS release 5.8.

Answer (score 1):

Native code populating properties from the below link(for solaris,Linux operating system )

Below native method loading system properties.

```
private static native Properties initProperties(Properties props);
```

Below link is the native code link for loading properties( after line number 187)

[Source for setting java properties](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/b3f231f73076/src/solaris/native/java/lang/java_props_md.c)